# Issue with BaTabBarController cocoapod controller (objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I need to hide previews image, how can i fix it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjlvD.gif

```
//create inner tab bar item
self.innerTabBarItem = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[self addSubview:self.innerTabBarItem];
self.innerTabBarItem.userInteractionEnabled = NO;//allows for clicks to pass through to the button below
self.innerTabBarItem.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

//create selected icon
self.selectedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:selectedImage];
self.selectedImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[self.innerTabBarItem addSubview:self.selectedImageView];

//create unselected icon
self.unselectedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:unselectedImage];
self.unselectedImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[self.innerTabBarItem addSubview:self.unselectedImageView];
```

Comment: if i m sure you want to remove middle image which shows when midddle button was unselect Right?

Comment: yes, want to delete/hide selected image when tabBarItem not selected.

Comment: put this code in  comment please  [self.innerTabBarItem addSubview:self.unselectedImageView];

Comment: error Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: sorry my bad put unselectedImageView hole code in comment just last try please

Comment: now it just dont set unselected img, but showing all selected img

Comment: try update for swift